# modal dialog login system

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to do is make a login system using modal dialog from bootstrap 3 with show and hide form using javascript. After the user successfully login it will redirect to `Profile form` using javascript code. My problem is after I click the login button the modal dialog disappears and nothing happens.

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#myLogin').submit(function() {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#pass').val();    

        $.ajax({
            data: {
             email : email, password : password
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: 'user.php',
            success: function(data)
            {
               $('#show').html(data);
               $(".show-page[data-page=Profile]").trigger("click");
            }
        });
            return false;
    });

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined" && localStorage.getItem('pageToShow')) {
        var pageToShow = localStorage.getItem('pageToShow');
         $('.page').addClass('hide');
         $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
    }
    $('.show-page').click(function(){
        var pageToShow = $(this).data('page');
         $('.page').addClass('hide');
         $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem('pageToShow', pageToShow);
        }

    $('.modal-btn').click(function() {
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
});  
</script>
```

index.php

```
<body>
<form method="post" id="elogForm" action="index.php">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
        <div class="container"  id="myLogin">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS AND PASSWORD TO LOG IN.</h5>    
                                    <div id="show"></div>                                   
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-horizontal">       
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                                                    <input type="email" id="lemail" name="email" value="<?php echo $unm ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Address..." required="required" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                                                    <input type="password" id="lpassword" name="password" value="<?php echo $pwd ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password..." required="required" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="staylogged" class="checkbox-inline" />
                                                <label>  &nbsp; Keep me logged in</label>  &nbsp; <b>|</b>
                                                <a href="" style="text-decoration:none">  &nbsp; Forgot your password?</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                <button type="submit" id="login" name="login" class="btn btn-primary show-page"  data-page="Profile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="container">
        <div class="page Home">
            <div class="row">
                <center>    
                    <h1>"Home"</h1>
                </center>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page Profile hide">
            <div class="row">
                <center>
                    <h1>"Profile"</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>  
</form>
</body>
```

user.php

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($email) && !empty($pass)){
        $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * from user WHERE email=? AND password=?");
        $st->bindParam(1, $email);
        $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $st->execute();

        if($st->rowCount() == 1){
            echo "Email verifies, Access granted";
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect Email or Password";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Please enter Email and Password";
    }  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works at the bottom you can read what the issues were:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

    <title>Modal Login</title>

    <!-- Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center; 
        }
    </style>
 </head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container" id="myLogin">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h5 class="modal-title">PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS AND PASSWORD TO LOG IN.</h5>    
                            <div id="show"></div>                                   
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form method="post" id="elogForm">
                                <div class="form-horizontal">       
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                                                <input type="email" id="lemail" name="email" value="<?php echo $unm ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Address..." required="required" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                                                <input type="password" id="lpassword" name="password" value="<?php echo $pwd ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password..." required="required" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="staylogged" class="checkbox-inline" />
                                            <label>  &nbsp; Keep me logged in</label>  &nbsp; <b>|</b>
                                            <a href="" style="text-decoration:none">  &nbsp; Forgot your password?</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                            <button type="submit" id="login" name="login" class="btn btn-primary show-page"  data-page="Profile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div><!--/.modal-body -->
                    </div><!--/.modal-content -->
                </div><!--/.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!--/.modal .fade -->
        </div> <!--/.row -->
    </div> <!--/.container -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="page Home">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Home</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page Profile hide">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Profile</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>

<!-- Core JavaScript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#elogForm').submit(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
        var email = $('#lemail').val();
        var password = $('#lpassword').val();    

        $.ajax({
        data: {email : email, password : password},
        type: "POST",
        url: 'user.php',
        success: 
            function(data) {
                $('#show').html(data);
                $(".show-page[data-page=Profile]").trigger("click");
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            }
        });

   });

    $('.show-page').click(function(){
        var pageToShow = $(this).data('page');
        $('.page').addClass('hide');
        $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem('pageToShow', pageToShow);
        }
    });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I changed to make it work:

1. Most importantly, in your submit function, the variables were getting the value of fields with id's of email and pass.  Those didn't exist.  Your id's are lemail and lpassword.
2. You were attempting to submit a form with an id that didn't exist.  Changed the selector to the id of your form elogForm.
3. Added event.preventDefault() so that the form wouldn't dismiss automatically on submit so that your error message could be displayed (though, the validation in your user.php will never run since the fields will always have values due to the fact that you are using html5 inputs).
4. Added the close modal to the success function after it displays the correct page.
5. Removed the return false (I think that was your attempt at preventDefault).
6. Cleaned up your html by wrapping the form around the form elements not the whole page, removing the `<center>` tags and making sure you had a col inside of your rows.

So, this works on my end, but here's the deal: You can't use it unless you promise me that you will never again use `<center>` tags ever, anywhere, even on a test page ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you problem is that you are triggering a submit event on a div (`$('#myLogin').submit(function()`) you should trigger click event on login button i suppose.

your button element is *login* su use

`$('#login').click(function()`

Submit event is for forms elements.

Refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for documentation.

Comment: ic...but how do i triger it to change to profile form after login succesfully?

Comment: im using single page only

Comment: Which error do you get? If you replace my code it is still not working? Is the post request successful?

Comment: If you replace the line of code that I have written in my answer does the code working? Is the ajax call executed? If yes is the call successful?